# I want to connect excel and unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-sheets

i want to connect Excel or Google Sheet to Unity. I want to extract values from them and apply them directly from Unity. I already tried this, but failed my all try. if you find many ways, tell all of them to me

I make google sheet and import sheet read unitypackage. but didn't work

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a spreadsheet file's contents in Unity you need to:

1. Save the Excel file as a CSV file by going to **File** > **Save As** and
   selecting the CSV format in the Save As dialog box.
2. Import the CSV file into Unity by going to **Assets** > **Import Package** > **Custom Package** and selecting the CSV file in the Import Package dialog box.
3. Use a plugin or script to read the CSV file in Unity. There are
   several plugins and [scripts](https://bravenewmethod.com/2014/09/13/lightweight-csv-reader-for-unity/) available that can help you read CSV
   files in Unity. For example, you can use the [EasyCSV plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/easycsv-121713), which
   can be found on the Unity Asset Store.
4. Once you have imported the CSV file and are able to read it in
   Unity, you can access the data in the file and use it in your game.